# include prototype function globally (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function to quickly replace words in a string (with multiple occurences):

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
  var target = this;
  return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

This function works as expected. I need this function in multiple components (files) and functions, so I add this function directly at the beginning of every file. Is there an easy solution to include this kind of functions globally to a project without adding it separately to every file?

**Edit:**

```
// strings.js
import React from 'react';
String.prototype.replaceAll = function (search, replacement) {
  var target = this;
  return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

Should I export this function or how can I import this function? Can I add `import strings.js` at the top of App.js?

Comment: Your code already does that (using prototype modification). You can also make the function global, but it's better to just create a module and `import` it everywhere you need it...

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you make this a utility function that you import rather than on the prototype. Even if you make `StringUtils` and make that global `window.StringUtils.replaceAll = function`

Answer (score 2):

If you modify the string prototype, your work is done. The function will be available everywhere immediately. However, you should be aware that modifying the prototype of types like String is frowned upon: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-why-not-modify-object-prototype/

Also, if you are using TypeScript, you won't see the new function without casting the string to some type of your own.

Comment: BTW, Nice explanation.